# how to retrieve input from a certain html id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
 <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-data2">
<table class="table table-data2" id="resulttable" style="display: block;">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>NSN</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>Price ($)</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Shipping</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="producttable">



        <!--  -->


        <form id="myform0"></form>

        <tr class="tr-shadow">

            <td style="width: 90px;">
                <div>123
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-1 btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" onclick="showproductmodal(123)">
                        Add Photos
                    </button>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>

                <span class="status--process">
                    <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id="Nomenclature" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="desc">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm " id="Qty" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e. 20 EA" style="width: 100px;">


            </td>
            <td class="desc">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id="Price" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e 900" style="width: 90px;">

            </td>

            <td>
                <span class="status--process">
                    <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="desc">
                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
            </td>

            <td class="status--process">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="shipping cost" style="width: 120px; height: 30px;"><br>

                <select name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" class="form-control-sm form-control" style="width: 120px;">


                    <option value="0">Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option #4</option>
                    <option value="5">Option #5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem(0)">Submit</button>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="spacer"></tr>


        <form id="myform1"></form>

        <tr class="tr-shadow">

            <td style="width: 90px;">
                <div>343
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-1 btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" onclick="showproductmodal(343)">
                        Add Photos
                    </button>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>

                <span class="status--process">
                    <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id="Nomenclature" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="desc">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm " id="Qty" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e. 20 EA" style="width: 100px;">


            </td>
            <td class="desc">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id="Price" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e 900" style="width: 90px;">

            </td>

            <td>
                <span class="status--process">
                    <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="desc">
                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
            </td>

            <td class="status--process">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="shipping cost" style="width: 120px; height: 30px;"><br>

                <select name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" class="form-control-sm form-control" style="width: 120px;">


                    <option value="0">Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option #4</option>
                    <option value="5">Option #5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem(1)">Submit</button>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="spacer"></tr>


        <form id="myform2"></form>

        <tr class="tr-shadow">

            <td style="width: 90px;">
                <div>212
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-1 btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" onclick="showproductmodal(212)">
                        Add Photos
                    </button>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>

                <span class="status--process">
                    <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id="Nomenclature" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="desc">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm " id="Qty" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e. 20 EA" style="width: 100px;">


            </td>
            <td class="desc">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id="Price" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e 900" style="width: 90px;">

            </td>

            <td>
                <span class="status--process">
                    <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
                </span>

            </td>
            <td class="desc">
                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;">
            </td>

            <td class="status--process">

                <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="shipping cost" style="width: 120px; height: 30px;"><br>

                <select name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" class="form-control-sm form-control" style="width: 120px;">


                    <option value="0">Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                    <option value="4">Option #4</option>
                    <option value="5">Option #5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem(2)">Submit</button>

            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="spacer"></tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

and I have a function that is triggered from the dynamically created created html

```
function postitem(index) {
   var formid='#myform'+index

    $('input').each(function(index){

     console.log($(this).val()); 
 });
}
```

the selector $('input') captures all the input value in the html, what I really want is for it to capture only the input within a given #id. So I tried

```
 $('#myform1 input').each(function(index){

     console.log($(this).val()); 
 });
```

and

```
$(formid).('input')
```

and none of them yielded any result. How can implement retrieving a input within a div id?

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: Probably you should use `$('#myform1').querySelector('input')`

Comment: `#myform1 input` - that would select all input fields that are _inside_ the element with the id `myform1`.

Comment: Your code `$('#myform1 input')` is true. test some things like your id ('myform1'). did you write upper case and lower cases truly? and do your input elements has value?

Comment: Is your input dynamic as well by any chance?

Comment: This question doesn't deserve downvotes, jone2 has clearly made some attempt and has outlined the problem (although the large amount of code is not the easiest to read)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the input very much directly without using the parent `$("#idInput")` or for accessing it through parent you can use `$('#myform1 #idInput')`. But make sure you have defined the ids of the element at the time of generation.

There is another way of doing it you can use it as array `$('#myform1 input')[index]`. Note the index should be the desired number of appearance your input.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $("input").parent( "#myform1" );
```

Answer (score 0):

As i said in my comment, your javascript codes are true. but there is two problem that cause you have not any result:

1. `#myform1` is blank.
2. In another form you have some `input` controls, but they have not any value.

Below I added an input with some value to your form #myform1 and test your code:

```js
$('#myform1 input').each(function(index){

     console.log($(this).val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform1"><input value="Some Thing" /></form>
```